# Targeting elements by id using $.each in jquery

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm trying to code a parallax effect where a background image of a specific div scrolls slightly slower than the window does. Each background image is tied to a specific element with an id. With the current setup, when the background image's position is updated as the window scrolls while the element is visible.

However, with the way I have it set up, both of the elements with background images begin to move when the first element comes into view. I'd like for each element's background image to only scroll when that specific element is in view.

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    var windowPosition = (windowTop + $(window).height());

$.each(['#background1', '#background2'], function(i, val) {
    var backgroundPosition = $(val).offset().top;   
    var backgroundBottom = backgroundPosition + 700;
    console.log(backgroundPosition);

    if (backgroundPosition < windowPosition && backgroundBottom > windowTop) {
        $(val).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-windowTop / 5 + 300) + 'px');
    }       
});




});
```

});

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxkkr/

Comment: Might be easier to just offset the background images further down.

Comment: Before I did that, I'd just create new variables for each specific element, then specific if statements to catch those variables. Was looking for a way to do it with less code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but you probably need to come up with a better calculation for parallax, because the parallax calculation should be relative to the visible div.

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxkkr/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        $.each(['#background1', '#background2'], function (i, e) {

            if (isScrolledIntoView(e)) {

                var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var parallax = '-' + parseInt(windowTop / 5) + 'px';

                console.log(e, ' in view with parallax: ', parallax);

                $(e).css({
                    'background-position': '0px ' + parallax
                });
            }
        });

    });

});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {

    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    var topOfView = elemTop + docViewTop;


    if (docViewBottom >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 4m1r. I came to the same conclusion, that my parallax calculation was wonky. Tested this in my jsfiddle, and it seemed to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    var windowPosition = (windowTop + $(window).height());

$.each(['#background1', '#background2'], function(i, val) {
    var backgroundPosition = $(val).offset().top;   
    var backgroundBottom = backgroundPosition + 700;
    console.log(backgroundPosition);

    if (backgroundPosition < windowPosition && backgroundBottom > windowTop) {
        $(val).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-(windowTop - backgroundPosition) / 5) + 'px');
    }       
});




});

});
```